# Outerjoin for undefined relationship SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I am trying to join a few tables with an outerjoin.
This is my code

```py
products = (
    db.session.query(Offers, Products, Brand, Categories, ProductImages)
    .outerjoin(
        Offers,
        Offers.product_id == Products.id,
        Offers.brand_id == Brand.id,
        Offers.category_id == Categories.id,
        Offers.product_id == ProductImages.product_id,
    )
    .filter(and_(now >= Offers.start_date), (now <= Offers.end_date))
    .order_by(Offers.product_name)
    .all()
)
```

I am getting this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Don't know how to join to <class 'app.models.Offers'>; please use an ON clause to more clearly establish the left side of this join
```

But I am assuming by mentioning "Offers" at the beginning of the join I am stating a join ON the "Offers" table.

There are no relationships defined for each of the tables and my tech lead has told me not to define it at the moment. How can I do the join without defining the relationships?

Comment: You query `(Offers, Products, Brand, Categories, ProductImages)`. Do you expect to receive a list of tuples of these classes?

Comment: @pi.A list of joined tuples with each class